# Filtering List using a drop-down selection value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, filter

I have an array of objects. Filtering of array of object based on selection of a dropdown value.

```
const itemsList=[{
"id":"123",
"problems":{
    "causes":[ 
         {
        "SSEnabled": true,
        "IndusEnabled": false,
        "LogEnabled": true
        }
    ]
}
},
{
"id":"234",
"problems":{
    "causes":[
          {
        "SSEnabled": false,
        "IndusEnabled": false,
        "LogEnabled": true
        }
    ]
}
}]
```

we have a drop-down to filter SSEnabled cause. The options of drop-down are "show","nofilter","exclude".

Need to filter the list based on dropdown selection.

If "show" option of "SSEnabled" dropdown is selected, the list item where "SSEnabled":"true" should be the result.(i.e; id:"123")

If "exclude" of "SSEnabled" cause is selected, the list item where "SSEnabled:false" should be the result.(i.e; id:"234")

If "nofilter" is selected , it should ignore the filter. (i.e; id:"123", id:"234")

```
filterList(filterType, filterValue, itemsList) {
   // filterType : SSEnabled (type of dropdown changed)
   //filterValue : show, exclude , no filter
itemsList.map((items) => {
  if (
    items &&
    items.problems &&
    items.problems.causes &&
    items.problems.causes.length
  ) {
    items.problems.causes.filter((cause) => {
       if (cause[filterType] === true && filterValue === 'show') {
        return true;
      }
      if (cause[filterType] === false && filterValue === 'exclude') {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
});

console.log(itemsList, 'filtered List');
}
```

But the list is not getting filtered. Please help in filtering.

Comment: use Array filter method

Comment: then inside your `map` method you are not returning anything

Comment: Array.map is the wrong tool.  Array.map is for when you want an output array with as many elements as the input array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clean what to do this would be to define a lookup of functions that implement your logic and then pass the correct function to `some()` (or `find()`). You can pass it in `field` like `show` or `exclude` and the `key` you want to filter on like `SSEnabled`

```js
const itemsList=[{"id":"123","problems":{"causes":[ {"SSEnabled": true,"IndusEnabled": false,"LogEnabled": true}]}},{"id":"234","problems":{"causes":[{"SSEnabled": false,"IndusEnabled": false,"LogEnabled": true}]}}]

// implement the selection logic based on keyword
// will return items where some of the cause match the condition
const filters = (field, key ) => {
    let options = {
     show:     (i) => i[key] == true,
     nofilter: (i) => true,
     exclude:  (i) => i[key] == false
    } 
    return options[field]
}

// filter using the above function:

let SSEnabled = itemsList.filter(item => item.problems.causes.some(filters('show', 'SSEnabled')) )
console.log(SSEnabled)

let SS_not_enabled = itemsList.filter(item => item.problems.causes.some(filters('exclude', 'SSEnabled')) )
console.log(SS_not_enabled)

let LogEnabled = itemsList.filter(item => item.problems.causes.some(filters('show', 'SSEnabled')) )
console.log(LogEnabled)
```

Comment: Can the SSEnabled in filters object be dynamic?? since I got more such attributes to filter like 'indusEnabled','logisticsEnabled'.

Comment: @user8599269, sure instead of a simple object lookup, make it a function that takes the attribute you are looking. See edit.